# How to create a folder if not exist in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I am writing pom.xml newly and i am trying to Delete a folder already existing and create a new folder.Is there a way to do this? I am looking something like this:

```
<executions>
<execution>
    <configuration>
        <tasks>
           <if><!-- I need to check if the folder exists and delete->
            <delete>
                <fileset dir="target/resources"/>
            </delete>
           </if>
            <mkdir dir="target/resources"/>
        </tasks>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of doing so? Usually you never need to manually create folders etc. that's handled by maven itself...

Comment: Do you know about the maven-clean-plugin to delete folders?

Comment: Yes i know about maven-clean plugin to delete folders, but i don't know how to use if condition.

Comment: @khmarbaise My main aim is to use if condition to delete, Can you please tell how to do that?

Comment: The maven-clean-plugin will not fail if the folder is not there, so just configure the clean plugin to delete the folder you want and you should be good

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing this. The second you jump into antrun you should start questioning your approach -- it's always wrong.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I am using maven clean now, thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: how about checking if a folder exists and then fail the build if it doesn't exists? e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55803395/maven-resources-plugin-build-wont-fail-if-directory-doesnt-exists

Answer (score 0):

using maven antrun plugin.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/target/resources" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Another option would be to use exec-plugin