# Maven Resources Plugin: Build won't fail if directory doesn't exists

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In my pom.xml... I have the following configurations:

Build plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-resources</id>
      <phase>validate</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${build.directory}/classes/static/</outputDirectory >
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <!-- this is defined in profiles -->
            <directory>${myResourceFolder}</directory>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Profiles definition:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>development</id>
      <activation>
        <!-- this profile is active by default -->
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <myResourceFolder>/myDevelopmentFolder</myResourceFolder>
      </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
      <id>production</id>
      <properties>
        <myResourceFolder>${env.MY_PRODUCTION_FOLDER}</myResourceFolder>
      </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Where ${myResourceFolder} is defined in different profiles which can either be:

- /myDevelopmentFolder
- MY_PRODUCTION_FOLDER

where "/myDevelopmentFolder" is my local development folder and "MY_PRODUCTION_FOLDER" is any folder defined as an environment variable in the production build.

These configurations compiles fine.

But I wanted to achieve is that, if any of this folder is missing,

> maven-resources-plugin should fail.

Is there anyway of achieving this in Maven?

Thanks,
Artanis

Answer (score 0):

1) First of all, I think it is bad approach to build different binaries for difference environments. Better to bundle all resources and just use proper resources at runtime

2) If you still want go this wrong way then you can try profile activation on missing file (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). This "build-breaker" profile should break build somehow. For example, it may include Maven Enforcer plugin (https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/usage.html) which bans resource plugin with explanatory message

Comment: I totally disagree with you, where can you find such thing now a days? just take for example angular and spring boot integration? where angular is deployed to a springboot (or just plain apache tomcat) server?

Comment: Lastly that doesn't have to be binaries, it can be pictures or images where the development has placeholder images and the production has the actual images. Do you still consider that wrong?

Comment: "where angular is deployed to a springboot" - I'm not suggesting to do so. However, *if* you bundle Angular stuff into SpringBoot jar *then* it should be one bundle for all environments.

Btw, why do you manage Angular stuff with Maven? They have `npm` tool for such things. 

"Lastly that doesn't have to be binaries" - I mean if you build some bundle to be deployed then it should be the same bundle deployed everywhere. Otherwise you beg for troubles.

Comment: I am not managing Angular with Maven. It is that my web server is a springboot application. And I am deploying it to a springboot container. If you are not suggesting to do so... there are already tons of examples in the internet...

Comment: "It is that my web server is a springboot application" - and my point there must be one(==same) `jar` file to be deployed to every environment - development, uat, prod etc To me it appears you are trying to build different `jar` files depending on selected profile. If you do not do so then ignore me.